# Проблема с z-index HTML

Tags: html

Здравствуйте. Есть код http://jsfiddle.net/9agc4psq/

```css
body{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 font-size:14px;
 color:#353535;
 font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.p0{
 padding:0;
}
.m0{
 margin:0;
}
a{
 font-size:14px;
 text-decoration:none;
}

.content{
 width:1024px;
 margin:0 auto;
}

.header{
  width:100%;
 background:#383838;
}

.header .menu ul{
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
}

.header .menu ul li{
 display:inline-block;
 position:relative;
}


.header .menu ul li a{
 color:#ccc;
 padding:10px 15px;
 display:block;
}

.header .menu .ul_gt_menu > li{
 /*margin:0 5px 0 0;*/
}
.header .menu .ul_gt_menu > li:hover{
 background:#4A4A4A;
}
.header .menu .ul_gt_menu > li:hover > a{
 color:#fff;
}

.header .menu ul li .block_menu_podpunkt{
 /*display:none;*/
 position:absolute;
 z-index:2;
 width:100%;
 padding:10px 0px;
 background:#fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px 1px #BFBFBF; 
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 4px 1px #BFBFBF; 
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 4px 1px #BFBFBF; 
 border-radius:0 0 2px 2px;
 -moz-border-radius:0 0 2px 2px;
 -webkit-border-radius:0 0 2px 2px;
}
 
.header .menu ul li .block_menu_podpunkt  > .conteiner_block_menu_podpunkt > ul > li{
 display:block;
}
.header .menu ul li .block_menu_podpunkt > .conteiner_block_menu_podpunkt > ul > li > div > a{
 color:#353535;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
 <header>
  <div class="header">
   <div class="content">
    <section class="menu">
      <div class="gorizontal_menu" id="block_menu_gorizontal">
      <ul class="ul_gt_menu">
      <li class="li_punkt_gt" onmouseover="open_block_podpunkt(this)" onmouseout="close_block_podpunkt(this)"><a class="punkt_a" href="/demo/10.1/alladv/"><div>Все объявления ▼</div></a><div class="block_menu_podpunkt">
                 <div class="conteiner_block_menu_podpunkt"><ul class="ul_podpunkt_gt">
<li class="li_podpunkt_gt"><div><a class="grup_a" href="/demo/10.1/newadv/"><div class="conteiner_grup_a"><div>Добавить</div></div></a></div></li><li class="li_podpunkt_gt"><div><a class="grup_a" href="/demo/10.1/edit/"><div class="conteiner_grup_a"><div>Редактировать</div></div></a></div></li></ul></div></div>
</li><li class="li_punkt_gt"><div class="raz_menu_punkts"></div></li><li class="li_punkt_gt" onmouseover="open_block_podpunkt(this)" onmouseout="close_block_podpunkt(this)"><a class="punkt_a" href="/demo/10.1/allobjectct/"><div>Все объекты</div></a></li></ul><div style="clear:both;"></div></div><script type="text/javascript" src="/demo/10.1/templates/orange/menu_gorizont_2_js.js"></script> 
    </section>
   </div>
  </div>
 </header>
 </body>
</html>



     
     
       







</body></html>
```

На выпадающем меню есть тень , она залезает на блок.. Не могу разобраться с z-index, чтобы тень спрятать за черный фон .. Спасибо

Answer (score 2):

```
.header .menu ul li .block_menu_podpunkt {
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: ну а ссылки потом в  ней?

Comment: @SarkisAllahverdian сформулируйте правильно свой вопрос.

Comment: @SarkisAllahverdian
Если нужно, можно сделать отдельно блок с только з-индекс для меню и отдельно для ссылок.

Answer (score 1):

1. Очень большая вложенность и как следствие перегруженный код. К примеру .header, .gorizontal_menu, .menu, .conteiner_block_menu_podpunkt, .conteiner_grup_a, пустой div внутри ссылки...эти блоки не нужны
2. Подумайте над именованием классов. (conteiner_grup_a, ul_podpunkt_gt )

```
.header {
  background: #383838;
}

.content {
  max-width: 1024px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.list {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;

  &__item {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
  }

  &__link {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}

.inner-list {
  @extend .list;
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px #000;

  &__item {
    padding: 10px;
  }

  &__link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
  }
}
```

```
<header class=header>
  <div class="content">
    <ul class="list">
      <li class="list__item">
        <a class="list__link" href="#">Все объявления ▼</a>
        <ul class="inner-list">
          <li class="inner-list__item">
            <a href="#" class="inner-list__link">Добавить</a>
          </li>
          <li class="inner-list__item">
            <a href="#" class="inner-list__link">Редактировать</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="list__item">
        <a class="list__link" href="#">Все объекты</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>
```